# No item display in canvas layout in PowerApp application

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I Started create App from empty canvas and connected it in to Mysql db and add some entry to the UI with some field when its test show empty canvas power app

Comment: Could you add some screenshots for your app, how did you mapped fields, are you using only editing form or also to show. More details would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Form.DefaultMode from .Edit to .New.